# Making siri count aloud

Tags: ios, siri

I wish to build an iOS app in swift which allows a user to set a number. When user taps on start, siri counts @ 1 count per second up to the number set by the user.
Is there a framework which supports this task?

Answer (score 2):

Use a Text-To-Speech framework like [AVSpeechUtterance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechUtterance_Ref/)
Example code:

```
int numberSpecifiedByUser = 99;
for (int i = 1; i <= numberSpecifiedByUser; i++) {
    NSString *numberAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:numberAsString];
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```

This will start at 1 and count to 99 reading out each number loud.
AFAIK, you can also specify the kind of voice to use in this framework. Please refer to Apple's documentation linked above.

P.s.: Sorry this is Objective-C but swift code should be very similar!